# tex4ht table of contents problems related to titlesec

Tags: titlesec, tex4ht

I am having a problem that titlesec is making the sections disappear from the tex4ht table of contents.  Here is the M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{\thesection.}{50pt}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents[chapter,section]

\chapter{One}%
qqqq
\chapter{Two}
\section{A}
aaaa
\section{B}
bbbb
\end{document}
```

Sections A and B do not appear in the html TOC.  When you comment out the `\titleformat` command, they do.  Same thing happens if you use `\titlesec[explicit]` without the `\titleformat` command.  A similar `\titleformat{\chapter}` command has no effect on whether the chapters appear in the html TOC.

I am producing the html using `htlatex test.tex`.  As of a few weeks ago, all my software was up to date.

Any help appreciated!

---

Edit 1:
In terms of a more complete tex4ht bug report, the following example also results in no sections in the TOC:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\ConfigureToc{section}{}{~}{}{ }
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}%
qqqq
\chapter{Two}
\section{A}
aaaa
\section{B}
bbbb
\end{document}
```

However, removing `[explicit]` from `titlesec` **or** commenting out the `\ConfigureToc` results in the sections being present.

Answer (score 2):

Since defined `\titleformat` cannot be used in html format directly anyway, I think it would be in your case best to use usual solution for unsupported visual commands with `tex4ht` -  use conditional processing:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\ifx\HCode\undefined
\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{\thesection.}{50pt}{}
\fi
\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents[chapter,section]
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}%
qqqq
\chapter{Two}
\section{A}
aaaa
\section{B}
bbbb
\end{document}
```

also note that I commented out

```
%\tableofcontents[chapter,section]
```

and replaced it with

```
\tableofcontents
```

because `[chapter,section]` showed in text after the toc

Comment: Thanks, @Michal! I will use this as a work-around. But it seems as though this is a bug in tex4ht. Is there a way to report it? There is another way to get the same (buggy) result, which I will edit into my question at the bottom. Also, I note that the html is actually different without the `\titleformat`, but I don't think that will make a difference to me.

Comment: @NatKuhn there is a bug database for `tex4ht` at https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?group=tex4ht, so please report it. AT least we should be able to block `\titleformat` from messing the sections